# Ordered forward lock-free list implemented in C

Tags: c, linux, lock-free

I need lock-free data structure that confirms to certain criteria: fast, low memory consumption, simple to implement, ordered. Have been searching, and found data structures such as single-linked list, doubly-linked list, skip lists, but none of them meet all my criteria. In my opinion forward list would fulfill those criteria. But I'm not aware of any existent implementation.

Is there any production-ready implementation  of forward lock-free list in C for Linux ?

Comment: Take a look at `libavl`.

Comment: A forward list is a ridiculously minor change to a singly linked list.  You just keep pointers to next and prev for each node.  Why not write one yourself?  It's about the easiest coding practice excersise for C.  Any relative beginner should build something of this sort at least once.

Comment: @wallacer Forward list yes, but lock-free forward list? Are you sure ?

Comment: Your criteria doesn't mention anything about asynchronous updating of the lists.  Unless you build locking into your list (to protect against asynchronous update errors), it will be lock free....  If you're planning to use this data structure in a multi-threaded environment, you might want to include that in your criteria

Comment: May want to check something like this out if you really need lock free synchronization
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/723555/A-Lock-Free-Doubly-Linked-List

Comment: @wallacer Lock-free, wait-free are used in context of multithreading.

Comment: @Eric Wang Skiplists are simpler to implement, and have the same properties as balance trees. But thanks

Comment: @wallacer Have read this, impemented, too slow. Need some forward algorithm to speed-up traversal. From prev->cur->next is too slow. I'm dealing with millions of elements. Have invented randomized lock-free algorithm (ins/del/find about 2000op/ms on 1m list), but it is also too slow.

Comment: Fixed-size FIFO with power-of-two size meets all requirements. Example implementation available at 1024cores.net.

Comment: @Damon Fixed size is not an option as does not meet memory consumption criterion, is not dynamic. Further lock-free ordered FIFO ?

Comment: @Filip Bulovic The traverse order is from the newest to the oldest added entry. Does not meet speed criterion.

Comment: @wallacer thanks, spent about 6 attempts to get it right. Guess it is best to check GitHub. For example this is implementation by Linus [https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/llist.h

Comment: I would probably use Linus's implementation.  He has a pretty decent track record ;)

Comment: @wallace this one is way better, simpler to understand [link](https://github.com/sefler1987/lf_table). But still it only downgrades to linked-list. as a matter of fact it's the base of my current algo.

Comment: Initial requirement was "low memory consumption", not "dynamic". Fixed size (e.g. 256 elems) is "low". Fast and dynamic are pretty much mutually exclusive since not only are the allocations/deallocations (or recycling) expensive but you also have a lot more work to do (pointer bit tampering) with ABA. Maybe explaining what you need this for could be helpful.

Comment: @Damon Well, fast and dynamic can be combined as in [link](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~gramoli/doc/pubs/ICDCS13-preprint.pdf) + memory management from [link](https://code.google.com/p/nbds/). What i need is some simpler solution, for server side processing of ordered uint64_t numbers in huge quantity. Forward lock-free list in my opinion would suite.

Comment: But why do you want a skip list or hash table if you want sequential access? Those are opposite things. Processing huge numbers of 64-bit integers in sequence is best done in a ringbuffer-alike structure, or better yet in a ringbuffer-of-buffers. You most certainly do not want to do billions of push/pop operations per second on a lockfree list, nor billions of allocations/deallocations per second (that simply doesn't work).

Comment: Worded differently, push buffers of 1,000 or 10,000 integers to a fixed-size circular buffer (which you can implement super fast in a lock-free manner) and pull a thousand (or ten thousand) numbers (a.k.a. tasks) at one time.

Comment: Two lock-free skiplists are by now my main choice. Well documented, available lock-free source code. Disadvantage - memory overhead. Pros - fast. I insert and delete randomly, but each time must know what was the previoius and the next element(before and after operation), therefore structure need to be ordered. That's why i opted for list-like structure. But want less memory consumption, and lighter approach.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/nbds/

There's a beta implementation of Lock Free Skiplists here.  They say it has no known bugs and is feature complete.

Comment: I comments below main question in my discussion thread as response to @Damon in context of memory management you can find this link (second link).

Comment: Ah, I didn't bother reading all the links in the comments.  In any event this answer provides one possible and legitimate solution.  If it doesn't work for your particular case, it can still help someone else in the future who happens across this post, so I think I'll leave it up.

Comment: It might indeed help someone in future. In my case it is the base line for analizing possible solutions. Already known, and not fulfilling main objectives, or at least not all of them. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ya, it seems like your requirements are demanding enough, and specific enough, that it's likely you're going to have to build something yourself to satisfy them.  I'm quite curious what the use case is

Comment: RT Delaunay triangulation-like project